# Exporting as pipe-delimited not working in MSSQL Server

Tags: export, sql-server-2014, delimiter

I am going to Tools->Option, (etc) and setting it to a Custom Delimiter of a `|` but when I export as text or export as a file, it keeps being tab-delimited instead.

I followed the instructions found at this URL (one example of a few saying the same thing)

https://mssqltrek.com/2012/07/24/obtaining-pipe-delimited-results-from-sql-server-using-ssms/

but it just comes out tab-delimited.

Am I missing something? This is SSMS 14.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, a restart of SSMS was needed.